# Why does redux-persist not work right on ajax calls?

Tags: react-native, redux, axios

So I loaded data with axios in my action like this:

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchQuestions(city) {
  return function (dispatch) { 
    axios.get('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/test123/tweets')
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_QUESTIONS_SUCCESS", payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_QUESTIONS_FAILURE", payload: err})
      })
  }
};
```

And it loads into questions in my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    questions: [],
    error: null,
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_QUESTIONS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        questions: action.payload
      };
    case types.FETCH_QUESTIONS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I call it like this on the first page of my app in the constructor:

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    if(!this.props.questions){
      this.props.actions.fetchQuestions();
    }
  }

So with that I want to only use it when questions is empty.

On another page when I do `console.log(questions)` it tells me questions is empty. While I did load it before so it should still be loaded since I am using `redux-persist`. 
When I click a button on that page and `console.log(questions)` again it does show the data.

Comment: are you using 'whitelist' of redux persist?

Comment: Yes I am and questions is in it

Comment: Can you post index.js of reducer and configure redux state code